# MATLAB Application with Python Files

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to compile an standalone MATLAB App which calls Python scripts. My code works while being used from MATLAB 2019b directly, but the callback in the standalone App (from APP Designer) does not work. How could I initialize this correctly? Is there any way to include the Python runtime in the MATLAB install? Can I manually include the Python runtime in the App installer and then install it from the included App files?

Thanks for the help!

I tried packaging the App from MATLAB's built-in App Designer but the scripts fail to run (because the runtime is not contained).